# Data is not being inserted into tables python, SQLAlchemy, postgresql, and pgAdmin4

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pgadmin-4

I am trying to insert the following data into two tables using a combination of python, sqlalchemy, postgresql, and pgadmin4. The primary keys should auto-populate in both tables based on the specifications of the script.

run_app.py

```
from run import db, Book, Publication

p1 = Publication("Oxford Publications")
p2 = Publication("Paramount Press")
p3 = Publication("Oracle Books Inc")
db.session.add_all([p1,p2,p3])

b1 = Book("Miky's Delivery Service", "William Dobelli", 3.9, "ePub", "broom-145379.svg", 123, 1)
b2 = Book("The Secret Life of Walter Kitty", "Kitty Stiller", 4.1, "Hardcover", "cat-150306.svg", 133, 1)
b3 = Book("The Empty Book of Life", "Roy Williamson", 4.2, "eBook", "book-life-34063.svg", 153, 1)
b4 = Book("Life After Dealth", "Nikita Kimmel", 3.8, "Paperback", "mummy-146868.svg", 175, 2)
b5 = Book("The Legend of Dracula", "Charles Rowling", 4.6, "Hardcover", "man-37603.svg", 253, 2)
b6 = Book("Taming Dragons", "James Vonnegut", 4.5, "MassMarket Paperback", "dragon-23164.svg", 229, 2)

db.session.add_all([b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6])
db.session.commit()
```

run.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(

    SECRET_KEY=########',
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='postgresql://postgres:########@localhost/catalog_db',
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False
)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# PUBLICATION TABLE
class Publication(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'publication'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'The Publisher is {}'.format(self.name)


# BOOKS TABLE
class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'book'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False, index=True)
    author = db.Column(db.String(350))
    avg_rating = db.Column(db.Float)
    format = db.Column(db.String(50))
    image = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    num_pages = db.Column(db.Integer)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())

    # ESTABLISH RELATIONSHIP
    pub_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('publication.id'))

    def __init__(self, title, author, avg_rating, book_format, image, num_pages, pub_id):

        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.avg_rating = avg_rating
        self.format = book_format
        self.image = image
        self.num_pages = num_pages
        self.pub_id = pub_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} by {}'.format(self.title, self.author)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However when executing run_app.py the follow error occurs:

```
psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table "book" violates foreign key constraint "book_pub_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (pub_id)=(1) is not present in table "publication".
```

Any way to make the tables auto-generate the primary keys and have them filled with the corresponding data?

Comment: How are you sure that the added Publication records have ids of 1,2,3? You seem to be relying on this being the case, and it is probably complaining because they aren't. Are they auto-increment fields?

Comment: Infact, why not refer to them as p1.id, p2.id, p3.id where being used in Book constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to capture the newly generated id field from the new Publication records, change run_app.py to:

```
from run import db, Book, Publication

p1 = Publication("Oxford Publications")
p2 = Publication("Paramount Press")
p3 = Publication("Oracle Books Inc")
db.session.add_all([p1,p2,p3])

b1 = Book("Miky's Delivery Service", "William Dobelli", 3.9, "ePub", "broom-145379.svg", 123, p1.id)
b2 = Book("The Secret Life of Walter Kitty", "Kitty Stiller", 4.1, "Hardcover", "cat-150306.svg", 133, p1.id)
b3 = Book("The Empty Book of Life", "Roy Williamson", 4.2, "eBook", "book-life-34063.svg", 153, p1.id)
b4 = Book("Life After Dealth", "Nikita Kimmel", 3.8, "Paperback", "mummy-146868.svg", 175, p2.id)
b5 = Book("The Legend of Dracula", "Charles Rowling", 4.6, "Hardcover", "man-37603.svg", 253, p2.id)
b6 = Book("Taming Dragons", "James Vonnegut", 4.5, "MassMarket Paperback", "dragon-23164.svg", 229, p2.id)

db.session.add_all([b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6])
db.session.commit()
```